# TFS Query for Displaying How Long Tasks Take To Go From Created to Closed

Tags: tfs-2015, excel-2016

TFS 2015 Update 3

How can I create a TFS query that will display a list of tasks and how long it took for the task to go from created to closed? Maybe I will need to create an Excel report for this? Or to export the report I have to Excel and then add formulas there? I would prefer to not have to add formulas in Excel, but it's okay if I do.

Here is what I have so far:

[image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

There is **no this kind of work item query will directly return the actual time taken** for a Task from active to closed.

Your workaround extracting the data to Excel to analyse works perfect. I thins this is the  simplest way to achieve what you want.

Moreover, you could also query the work item history with the TFS API and check the times tamps on when the state transitions occurred.